# Looking for a book featuring an amazon-like all women tribe, title possibly contains the word "fyre"

Tags: story-identification

I read a book couple of years back about a tribe of all female warriors.

The only way they would reproduce was to take a man from some other place. After giving birth, if the baby was a girl they would keep it.

They never named the babies, I forgot why. But they did call her by the word she always said when she pointed at something.

I think it also mentions the word "fyre" in the title.

That's all I have to go on because I didn't get to finish it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the SF & Fantasy stack. Is there anything else you remember about the book? When was "a couple of years back"? In what language was it? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Anything else, as insignificant as it may seem? Sometimes small details help a user find a book. O, if you have the time, please take the [tour].

Comment: Long shot: Queen of the Amazons by Judith Tarr. Hyppolyta's daughter is born without a soul--she can ride and hunt but not feed nor dress herself. One day the girl hears about a conqueror from the west (Alexander) and heads off.

Answer (score 3):

I'm searching for this book as well and this is what I remember about it: I read this book back in 2004, and it's about a girl; I think her name was "Rain" and she was the best horseback rider/warrior in a tribe of women from the Amazon. Her mother was raped by something like 100 men, so she was never accepted by her mother. But I think she fell in love with a man named Michael. I think the title was just one word, or "The" something. It had a dark cover, with some blue on it, and I think the girl's face on it.

I found it! It's called *The Foretelling* by Alice Hoffman.

Comment: I found it! It's called The Foretelling by Alice Hoffman

Comment: :) Well, [edit] that in as an answer if you think it's the same book.